# Limit queryset on Django 2 autocomplete_field

Tags: django, django-admin

For a long time we've been overriding our ModelAdmin's `formfield_for_foreignkey` to limit the queryset the field can choose from. Here's a simplified version of what I mean:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "site":
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs["queryset"] = request.user.site
```

But I recently added this field to the `autocomplete_fields` definition (to get some Select2 gravy). The result was I now see no suggestions as a non-superuser account.

Is there a more right way to limit the queryset, or is this a simple bug in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs a patch that's still in dev. You can be patient, or you can monkey-patch  `AutocompleteJsonView.has_perm` as I am below. I just stuck this in settings.

If you're also stuck on 2.0.x (as I currently am *shakes fist at Wagtail*) you'll also need to make sure your ModelAdmins define a `has_view_permission`.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.autocomplete import AutocompleteJsonView
def ac_has_perm(self, request, obj=None):
    return self.model_admin.has_view_permission(request, obj=obj)
AutocompleteJsonView.has_perm = ac_has_perm
```