# Limit the queryset of autocomplete fields in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a `ModelAdmin` in Django 2.1.3 like this:

```
class BoxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['testkit']

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'testkit':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Barcode.objects.exclude(testkit__in=Box.objects.all().values('testkit'))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method is written for "traditional" foreign key fields. For the autocomplete field it ensures that an error is displayed when a testkit outside of the queryset is selected. It doesn't however limit the results found in the autocomplete field. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) does not mention any restrictions for custom querysets. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982701/5119485) is related but only deals with authorization.

It is possible to override the [`get_search_result`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) method of the related `ModelAdmin`.

```
class TestkitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['number']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if 'autocomplete' in request.path:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(testkit__in=Box.objects.all().values('testkit'))
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

But I don't find a way to determine from which autocomplete field the search request came. Thus I can only program it to meet the needs of one referencing `ModelAdmin`.

How can I correctly limit the queryset of the autocomplete field?

Answer (score 5):

This question look hold but I've seen many people keep asking for it and other give very complicated answers..

Then the simplest way to limit the autocomplete list is to limit the queryset by surcharging the **get_search_results**
or the **get_queryset** inside the **related object’s ModelAdmin**

Now to know when its **called by** your autocomplete field you have:

- request.path : that will always contain 'autocomplete' string
- request.GET.get('model_name') : model name, on your exemple its the
  model 'box'
- request.GET.get('field_name') : field name, on your exemple its the
  field 'testkit'

Then your code should look like that:

```
class TestkitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['number']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if 'autocomplete' in request.path and request.GET.get('model_name') == 'box' and request.GET.get('field_name') == 'testkit':
            queryset = queryset.exclude(testkit__in=Box.objects.all().values('testkit'))
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the Django `autocomplete.js` static file in `static/admin/js/autocomplete.js`. Django will always prefer the file you have overwritten.

Then in the overwritten file modify the `djangoAdminSelect2()` function something like this:

```
$.fn.djangoAdminSelect2 = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, options);
    $.each(this, function(i, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        $.extend(settings, {
            'ac_field_name': $element.parents().filter('.related-widget-wrapper').find('select').attr('name')
        });

        init($element, settings);
    });
    return this;
};
```

and the `init()` function like this:

```
var init = function($element, options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        ajax: {
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term,
                    page: params.page,
                    field_name: options.ac_field_name
                };
            }
        }
    }, options);
    $element.select2(settings);
};
```

Then in your `get_search_results()` just access the request GET parameter `field_name` and voila.

Of course you can make the JS look nicer, but in principle it works like this.

Comment: I am using this on a model that has several ForeignKeys to the same model where I wanted different autocomplete options for each ForeignKey. I'm not skilled with javascript, but I figured out that ac_field_name is populated on page load, and only contains one value, not one per field. So I reverted to the original autocomplete.js and just added `field_name: $element.attr('name')` into the init function return dict (making sure to add a comma on the previous line!). I overrode autocomplete.js site-wide as I could not get the ModelAdmin's Media class js to load after django's js.